# Is extracting data from YAML faster than database or constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, memcached

Is extracting data from YAML faster than from a database or a constant?

In this situation, there are 7000 keys and the keys values will never change.

Example:

```
def function_in_controller
  # Solution 1
  Rails.cache.fetch('key_1',expires_in: 1.year) do
    data_1 = I18n.t ('data_key_1')
  end
  # Solution 2
  Rails.cache.fetch('1',expires_in: 1.year) do
    data_1 = Model.where(key:1) 
  end
  #Solution 3
  KEYS=[{key_1},{key_2},....,{key_7000}] 
end
```

On average, a key contains 1kB data and the total size of data is 8.5MB.

Comment: YAML is not a substitute for a database; It's great for configuration information where it rarely changes and one or two people are responsible for its maintenance and you don't want to give people access to the file system. A database is great for configuration where information changes more often, there are people responsible for changing that information, and they should NEVER touch the file system. 7000 keys is excessive for YAML I think, and I'd have moved it to a DB a long time before it got to that size.

Comment: Is YAML faster? Usually, because it's usually locally stored and doesn't have to be pulled across the network. Is that important? Usually not because data from the database is pulled in chunks as a result of select statements, not in its entirety, so they're much smaller and can move much faster. I think you're asking about apples and oranges.

Comment: "a key contains 1kb data"? One kilobit?

Comment: No its 1KByte, what about storing it in constant? I just checked CONSTANT size it took 1.5MB to store all key_values

Comment: A YAML file is marginally better than a constant. Putting data that could change, that requires recompilation or retesting, into a constant isn't good. Separate data from code, especially configuration data, but either way keep them separate.

Comment: I completely agree with @theTinMan about you’re comparing apples and oranges, but what would be the issue to indeed _compare_ times if you are interested in what’s faster? Also, for cached key-value pairs, people usually use kinda key-value storage, like Redis. Also, this happens once upon the application start and for the whole year, so it absolutely does not matter what’s faster.

Comment: Use the class Benchmark to figure out which one is better for your given scenario. As people have pointed out, this is a very open-ended matter.